# Stripe API to transfer one customer to another customer

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I need to integrate stripe payment below use-case

I have two customers, customer one wants to send the money to customer two, how we can achieve this ??.

I have one idea when customer one send money to customer two means, we can move money owner of the stripe getway, then we will move money owner account to customer t

I'm using PHP SDK

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with Stripe Customers, but you can ~do it with [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/).

That said, I'd recommend you write into Support first and make sure they can support your use case: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email